# Failed to install react-native-navigation module. Thrown error "ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: npm-install, react-native-navigation

I tried installing [react-native-navigation (by wix)](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/) package quite a few times using npm. The process was initiated, but for some reason it was not getting completed. I cancelled it in first attempt, and proceeded with installation again. For some reason npm was unable to install the package and started exiting with following error:

```
679 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\Workspace\pokemonn\node_modules\hoist-non-react-statics' -> 'D:\Workspace\pokemonn\node_modules\.hoist-non-react-statics.DELETE'
680 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
681 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

I'm on Window machine, with node 10.x LTS & npm 6.x & react-native 0.57.8 installed.

Comment: sometimes it will be the issue with npm, please post the package.json of you project. just delete the node_modules folder and package_lock.json file and then update the npm version to the latest by the command "npm install -g npm" and then run the "npm install" command. It worked for me.
I used to use a windows PC but not anymore. and sometimes you have to open your command prompt in administrative mode and then try "npm install" this also worked for me sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue got resolved much earlier, I forgot to update here.

There was a thread open on github which I found later related to npm installation. After following the steps mentioned, I was able to install it.
Following are the steps:

Delete both **node_modules** directory, and **package-lock.json** file from project folder
type `npm cache clean --force` and hit Enter
type `npm install -g react-native-navigation` and hit Enter

[More: [Github article]](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/261#issuecomment-207623445)